# How to prevent multiple logins using same username?

Tags: java, postgresql

I am developing an application which works over a local network. It uses javafx 8 in the frontend an a Postgresql server in the backend. The database is present in the database server in the network. In the server we have a table that stores the user details including the encrypted password and the user id. We use this table to authenticate the user who wishes to login.

Now we want to prevent the same userid from multiple computers in the network to login to the application. To this effect we had tried to create a column `loggedin` in the table storing user details. Then store boolean values true and false in the column. So, when the user has been authenticated successfully, we store `true` against the user id in the column `loggedin`. And when the user logs out then we update to table to store `false` in the column.

This process gave rise to a new problem. If the application is closed without user logging out, The user will never be able to login again. Also if the user's computer is shut down without the user logging out will give the same result. And if for any reason the server is restarted, then all the users that were logged in would never be able to login again.

I tried to find other solutions but am unable to find any. It would be very helpful if any one could give me other suggestions.

Comment: @Enzokie could you be a little more elaborate?

Comment: Invalidate the token for every login means that every logged account represents a value that serves as credentials, when the token is invalidated on the request, that means somebody logged the same credentials. A token is just a piece of string unique for every loggin atempt.

Comment: You can create a service that will invalidate the session when your front-end do not send a periodically heartbeat.

Comment: setting it on database is not guaranteed because there are scenarios that the application could not detect if it is closed. like what if the pc has many shutdown unexpectly or the application has been force closed or what ever. ever heard of socket.io server?

Comment: @NewbeeDev your question could sound nicer

Comment: Just don't implement that silly requirement. As simple as that. There is no reason to prevent user to log in from several machines. It only harms the user, doesn't bring any additional safety, and makes your system more complex. I am logged in StackOverflow on my laptop, my phone, and my office workstation. Why couldn't I do that?

Comment: @JBNizet, depends on the application ... Some licensed application using cloud checked that and ask if you want to kill the other connection to be able to continue (some Game Plateforme using Online content for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give every user their own database role, Postgres can handle this for you (along with the rest of the authentication process):

```
CREATE USER <username> PASSWORD '<password>' CONNECTION LIMIT 1
```

This has a number of other benefits, like fine-grained access control via [grants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) and [row-level policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html), and access to a much wider range of [authentication methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html).

If this isn't an option, the simplest approach is probably to acquire a [session-level advisory lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) on login, i.e.:

```
SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(<userid>)
```

This will return `true` if you have successfully acquired the lock, or `false` if the lock for that `userid` is already held by someone else. Once acquired, the lock will be held for the rest of your session, and will be automatically released on disconnect.

Keep in mind that you're just locking an arbitrary number, so you need to be sure that no other process is locking the same number for an unrelated reason. A common way of managing this is to call the two-argument version of `pg_try_advisory_lock()`, and scope the lock to your `users` table by passing in the table's internal identifier:

```
SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock('users'::regclass::int, <userid>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll disagree with your conclusions. It's obvious that at the application start, noone is logged in, so you can simply query for logged users on application start and update them with `logged_in = false`.

Another thing is the heartbeat - ping the user every 10 minutes. If there is no answer, force logout which results in setting `logged_in = false`.

Comment: Well there is no server side of the application to start. the server side only contains the database.

Comment: @Blip but you can use a heartbeat

Comment: could you be a bit elaborate about the heatbeat concept?

Comment: Without changes in your architecture, you can instead of having true/false in your db, keep `null` or `dateOfLastBeat`. Every 10 minutes execute update the date and in case someone wants to log in, if dateOfLastBeat is earlier than now()-10min invalidate that login and log new user

Comment: Arg, you add the heartbeat line during my answer ^^ kind of the sames here.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a Database from the server as said in comment *Well there is no server side of the application to start. the server side only contains the database. – Blip*

I would use the database to store a value `lastQuery` that should be updated during some action. This should be cleared during the logoff. If you tried to login with this values, you either refuse (risk if there was a crash, so no logoff) or ask if you want to clear the other previous connection.

This values would be a `timestamp` to know when was the last action done or using a "ping" that will say your connection (application) is still alive (invalidate the `timestamp` if one or two pings are missed (delay from timestamp bigger than the frequency between pings). That would be used to automaticly logoff a user after some time if you need.

Can't say more without more information